# Base 64 pdf is not displayed in IE11

Tags: pdf, gwt, base64, internet-explorer-11, embed

I'm trying to display a pdf File with GWT with the following html code :

```
HTML pdfHtml = new HTML("<embed src='data:application/pdf;base64," + myPdfStringBase64 + "' width='100%' height='370px'></embed>");
```

It seems like the pdf String is too big for IE and it is automatically cutted from the 4096 character.
However this works fine with Chrome and Firefox...

Does anyone has to deal with such an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is

```
if (isInternetExporer) downloadPdf()
```

You can download using something like filesaver.js. Wrapping this in GWT is just a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in my case i really need to get the pdf displayed. Actually it works when i use servlets (in this case the IE limitation is most probably not the same) but still i need to perform this on the client side, so directly in GWT !

Comment: IE has an URL limit of 4096 characters. And since you are building up a data: URL you are hitting the limit of IE.

I think it is just impossible to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: After few researchs it seems like the url size can be overpassed with an IFrame, hoxever the pdf is still noit displayed ...
Any Ideas ?